# TensorflowJS: Training multiple models simultaneously (for performance)

Tags: tensorflow.js

In my project, I am training many small graphs.  Seeing as how the work is being done on the GPU, and the GPU is running at a low 5%, would it make sense to train many graphs simultaneously for a performance boost?  I'm just a bit concerned, as I know JS isn't really a thread-capable language.

Are there any other things I could look for to improve training performance?

Comment: If you don't need training on your clients devices just don't use a browser machine learning library.

Comment: yes, that would make things much simpler, wouldn't it  :-)

Comment: 5% is pretty cold.  Have you tried larger batch sizes?  Is there significant CPU work that takes place between ops?  Are there many small layers?

Answer (score 0):

In theory when training on the GPU with Tensorflow.js, you've got a number of elements that  all need balancing:

### 1: GPU usage

Of course, the amount that the GPU is being used matters - the ultimate goal is to max out the GPU to train as efficiently as possible in terms of time.

If you're seeing low GPU usage, your bottleneck is likely somewhere else in the picture - see below.

### 2: Javascript CPU usage

As you note, Javascript is not really a thread-based language. To this end, one has to watch the CPU usage of the main Javascript thread. If it's maxing out a CPU, then that's probably the bottleneck. A number of things can be done ot improve the situation:

- If you're training multiple models, try training them in different processes. In the browser this means WebWorkers (assuming that WebWorkers are compatible with Tensorflow.js); for Node.js this means multiple processes (e.g. with [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) (careful of transferring lots of data between processes - it's *slow*), or perhaps [threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) (though I haven't personally tried that).
- If you have a lot of preprocessing steps to get your data  into the right format, try doing some of these ahead of time to speed things up. Also check to see if the layers in your model will take a slightly different format in that's less work to convert to.

### 3: GPU memory usage

A limiting factor to the number of models that can be trained in parallel on a given GPU is the amount of memory that they use. Most dedicated GPUs use their own special dedicated VRAM, which can be quite limited. Check with your GPU manufacturer or OS provider to see how to monitor this.

### 4: I/O bandwidth

If neither your CPU nor your GPU are maxed out, then your issue is probably bandwidth. This can be in several places:

- Loading the original data in the first place
- Data transfer between the CPU & GPU during the training process (as @BlessedKey notes increasing the batch size can help here, but be careful of the increase in memory usage)
- Data transfer between processes on the CPU (this is *slow* - especially in Node.js) - try loading the data directly in the process that is going to use it

### Conclusion

Sorry for the long answer. This is sort of for my own reference as much as it is in answer of your question. Anyway, to summarise:

- Try training multiple models in parallel
- Be careful of i/o memory bandwidth
- Monitor performance closely to see if you gain a net increase in training speed